# Javascript .splice() and .push() error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array array1 and i store its copy in another variable say array2.
Now when i try to push a value to array1, the value gets pushed in array2 aswell even though array2 is assigned before pushing value to array1.
this happens in .splice() method too.

```
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = array1;
array1.push(4);
alert(array1);
alert(array2);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg3390kv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has primitive types and reference types.Array is a reference type. `Array2` get the reference, so the modification of the `array1` will affect the `array2`.you can also use this code:

```
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = array1.concat();
array2.push(4);
alert(array1);
alert(array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone your first array like this :

```
var array2 = array1.slice(0);
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg3390kv/1/)